# android JNI: app stops working

Tags: java, android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm new to android programming,I think the reason for the app to stop working lies here -> I want to return char array from **JNI(in c)** back to android(**java**)

```
     for(int c=0;c<length;c++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 36; k++) {
            if (a[c] == string2[j]) {
                S[c]=string2[j];
            }
        }
    }
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, jstring1, str);
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,S);
```

and in java:

```
 public native String HelloWorld(String stri);
```

and since I want to put whatever the output is in a **TextView**

```
 t3.setText(HelloWorld(str));
```

The program runs on the emulator but once I enter something in EditText and hit a button it stops responding and then closes.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's just a typo but I think you have to use k as the index inside the second loop.

You have:

```
for(int c=0;c<length;c++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < 36; k++) {
        if (a[c] == string2[j]) {
            S[c]=string2[j];
        }
    }
}
(*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, jstring1, str);
return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,S);
```

And it should be:

```
for(int c=0;c<length;c++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < 36; k++) {
        if (a[c] == string2[k]) {
            S[c]=string2[k];
        }
    }
}
(*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, jstring1, str);
return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,S);
```

Note the change inside the inner loop.

Comment: The problem still persists, are you sure the proper way to return the result is through "return (*env) -> NewStringUTF(env,S)" is correct?

Comment: No, I don't get any errors when I build and run the project, it stops responding for some time in the emulator when I enter a text and hit enter PS. I also tried using different emulator

Comment: Please post the complete code involving those methods so we can try and reproduce the case.